# Search and replace of function format in code

Tags: regex, bash, perl, vim

Is it possible to convert occurrences of the following string in my code:

```
foo(a,d);
```

to

```
foo(a) = d;
```

Comment: I do lots of refactoring (including fully automated one) and have to warn you that the answers below are all slightly *wrong*: they do not (and can not properly) handle cases when the `a` and `d` (the arguments) are not trivial expressions.

Answer (score 3):

In Vim you can use a substitution command like this:

```
:%s/\v(\w+)\((\w+),(\w+)\)/\1(\2) = \3/g
```

This will look for the form `func(arg1,arg2);` and convert to `func(arg1) = arg2;`

I am using the `\v` in this expression so that Vim uses [`very magic`](http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/31.html#very-magic) mode which makes it's much closer to standard Perl RegEx notation. (See @FDinoff's comment to show how much less readable it will be without)

Comment: What is the \v for ?

Comment: @TheLoneJoker that is to make my regex use "very magic" mode. It basically makes Vim's regex engine act like the Perl regex engine. I don't know if using that is necessary for my particular command but I almost always use it just to keep me sane :)

Comment: It looks like this without `\(\w\+\)(\(\w\+\),\(\w\+\))` so... probably worth it in this case for readability's sake.

Comment: You really shouldn't be asking that downvotes be explained, but in this case it was mine, because `\v` in vim is a *very* specific use of that sequence. In PCRE it means *vertical whitespace* and matches linefeed, line tab, form feed and carriage return, plus some non-ASCII characters. I downvoted before I noticed the `vim` tag on the question, and now I am unable to revoke it. But I think it's best to raise a flag against this non-standard usage anyway

Comment: I suggest that [Borodin](http://stackoverflow.com/users/622310/borodin)'s comment be added to the answer, or explicitely brought to attention.

Comment: @Borodin Thanks for replying. But hold on a sec...in PCRE the `\v` may be something particularly noteworthy, but in Vim using `very magic` mode is standard. So standard that I didn't even feel it needed extra expanation in my original answer. See https://davitenio.wordpress.com/tag/very-magic-mode/

Comment: In any case, I'll update my answer to make it more obvious that I'm using "very magic" mode

Comment: @Jonathan.Brink: Because of the OP's tags, people will be arriving at this question looking for Perl regex solutions. Only a minority of them will be interested in a vim-only solution, and it would be best not to misdirect them

Comment: Not knowing vim, please would you describe what `/\v(\w+)\((\w+),(\w+)\)/` does that `/(\w+)\((\w+),(\w+)\)/` does not?

Comment: @Borodin see FDinoff's comment in this thread to see the difference. Vim's default regex syntax is very weird so it's a very common practice to use "very magic" mode to use a more standard syntax

Answer (score 1):

It can be done with `sed`

```
 sed 's:\(\w\+\W\w\+\)\(,\)\(\w\+\)\();\):\1)=\3;:g' < $file > $OutFile
```